# QImage without using scaled() makes program crash when rendering on QML

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qml, qimage

I want to render images from the webcam onto QML view. And I have to transfer the format from OpenCV to `QImage`. Then I implement a `QQuickPaintedItem` singleton class to render `QImage`.

If I don't use `QImage::scaled()` in my code when I start grabbing and invoking rendering, my program crashes and I don't know why.

```
image=cv::Mat(stImageInfo.nHeight,stImageInfo.nWidth,CV_8UC3,m_pBufForSaveImage);

//cv::Size dsize = cv::Size(round(0.33 * stImageInfo.nWidth), round(0.27 * stImageInfo.nHeight));
//cv::Mat shrink;
//resize(image, shrink, dsize, 0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA);
QImage Qimag = MatImageToQt(image);
Qimag = Qimag.scaled(image.cols*0.33,image.rows*0.27,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
MyImage *myimg = MyImage::instance();
myimg->setM_Image(Qimag);
```

```
//render QImage to QML
#include "myimage.h"
MyImage::MyImage(QQuickPaintedItem *parent)
{
   Q_UNUSED(parent)
}

MyImage* MyImage::myImage = new MyImage;

MyImage *MyImage::instance()
{
   return myImage;
}

void MyImage::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
   QRectF target(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 550.0);//width*0.33 height*0.27
   QRectF source(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 550.0);
   painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
   painter->drawImage(target, this->m_Image, source);
}

const QImage &MyImage::getM_Image() const
{
   return m_Image;
}

void MyImage::setM_Image(const QImage &mimage)
{

   if (mimage != m_Image) {
       m_Image = mimage;
       emit m_ImageChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: What if you don't reuse `Qimag`? `QImage Qimag_2 = Qimag.scaled(image.cols*0.33, ...)` `...` `myimg->setM_Image(Qimag_2);`

Comment: Yes. ‘’‘myimg->setM_Image(Qimag.scaled(...));‘’‘ is efficient for FPS.

Comment: what is `MatImageToQt` and what is its code?

Comment: It's because your data the QImage is using goes out of scope as explained in the doc for the [QImage ctor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-6)